# Aspects of "Access to Moderator Tools"

Tags: support

So, I hit a rep threshold and now apparently have access to moderator tools, whatever that means.

In the page https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools I see a paragraph like this:

```
More!

This privilege also grants you access to the following lists:

Posts with extreme votes
Posts with the most comments/views/edits
Recently protected questions
Recently closed/reopened questions
Recently migrated questions [...]
```

There are no links to these lists, though. Question: Where/how do I access these "lists"? How am I expected to find these URLs? Is there a link to a manual or user guide that I have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have access to these tools from the *review* button in the SE top panel. This is set to reviews by default but you can change this view to the *tools* view:

[image]

This will then give you a selection of various tools:

[image]

For usage of any of these tools ask here, in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/499/german-language), or search for a topic on [Meta Stackoverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) which is valid here too.